# python multi-processing on writing file and return value

Tags: python, multiprocessing, file-writing

After reading data from database, I want to return data and write it to a csv file. How to use multi-processing to do it?

```
def get_data():
    data = get_data_from_database() #a dataframe
    data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False) #step 1: write to csv file
    return data #step 2: return data
```

How to use multi-processing to do step 1 and step 2?

Comment: There is no place for what we commonly call *multi-processing* here. Multi-processing (resp. multi-threading) is normally executing same task by multiple processes (resp. threads). Here you could use a pipeline: process_reading_database -> process_writing_csv_and_passing data -> process_using_data

Comment: Thanks. As it takes time to write the csv file, I do not want to wait for the process of writing file to finish and return. I want to concurrently writing file and return the data, not sequential processes.

Comment: You're looking for something like Node.js `streaming` ?

Comment: Not exactly but quite similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean multi-threading?  If yes, then if you want to write to the file somewhere else you should use locks and it can become a pain in the code!

But if you are not worried about that you can do something like this

```
import threading

def thread_write(data):
    data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)  # step 1: write to csv file

def get_data():
    data = get_data_from_database() #a dataframe
    t = threading.Thread(target=thread_write, args=(data,)) #pass your function as target of thread, and it's input variables as a tuple to args
    t.start()
    return data  # step 2: return data
```

Comment: Thank you very much, hamid sajjadi.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
def get_data():
        data = []
        data = get_data_from_database() #a dataframe
        if len(data) >0:
           for i in range (len(data)):
           data[i].to_csv('data.csv', index=False) #step 1: write to csv file
        return data #step 2: return data
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to to write csv file and return data simultaneously. How to do it?